# How do you sort a list of integers by ascending order?

Tags: python, list

(List name is b)
I tried using b.sort() but it just orders the numbers from 1 to 9 and ignores numbers that are bigger than this. How could I fix this?

---

For example, if I have the list

```
['1', '22', '5', '3', '8', '7', '90']
```

I would like to get

```
['1', '3', '5', '7', '8', '22', '90']
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

Comment: When you say that .sort() is ignoring numbers larger than 9, can you provide an example of the output you are getting, to compare to the output you expect? .sort() is the correct function for sorting lists and it should sort in ascending order by default.

Comment: @matts they are strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
print(sorted(list))
```

You are running into issues because you are using a list of strings. It is sorting them alpha-numerically. You do not enclose numbers in quotations.

Seems like you could benefit from [reading the docs.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = ['1', '22', '5', '3', '8', '7', '90']
x.sort(key=int)
print(x)
```

http://pythonfiddle.com/